# Nested rules not compile by less.js

Tags: less

I try to use less but I have a big problem by nested rules. I have this code:

```
.imageContainer{
    width:0;
    overflow:visible;
    img {
        position:absolute;
    }
}
```

Dreamweaver doesn't know these rules and it doesn't compile.

Comment: And what is "Dreamviewer"?

Comment: Did you actually install anything for the Dreamweaver to support Less? It does not support Less compilation out of the box.

Comment: And how do you use less.js? Note that less.js (neither script nor command line compiler) does not itegrate into Dreamweaver unless you've intsalled a didicated Dreamweaver plugin/extension... (So "using less.js" does not make Dreamweaver to compile less files) Well, here's hint: http://bit.ly/1p6KIYG

Comment: no no i use less.js inline in project.

Comment: just say me why this syntax is incorect?

Comment: other syntax like variable working in my project.! but when i use nested rules return eror :(

Comment: Well, the syntax *is* valid, that's why I'm asking all those questions. Ok, now we know that at least you get a error (not just "it doesn't compile") now assuming we are not telepathists here how many more questions we need to ask to find out what the error message is? (Hint: please provide as much information as possible, things like "it does not work", "it does not compile" etc. are absolutely useless).

Comment: just say to me this is a true syntax or wrong?

Comment: See my previous comment, it's been said there.